# How to navigate To and Back from Push Notification setup Page after user enabled it

Tags: swift3

I used below code to detect if user has enabled push notification.

```
**Problem**.
1) How to open or navigate to the Push Notification setting Page in the phone
2) How to return from this Push Notification page after user enabled it or
   how user return to previous page if decide to enable later.

VC_Check  -->  Push Notification settings 

in VC_check:

if UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
            print("YES")

    // goto other VC

  } else {

   // goto Phone setting page

  }


//-- I dont want this Pop Up to enable Push Notification:

// detected not enabled, use below pop Up

pageUIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can ask to enable push notification like this:

```
func requestNotificationPermission() {
        let app = UIApplication.shared

        // --- from right here
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            app.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        app.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                // DO SOMETHING HERE AFTER USER AUTHORIZES, CALL A FUNCTION TO RELOAD VIEW?
            }
            app.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions

        }
  }
```

To check if user has granted permission use this:

```
func checkNotificationStatus() {
        let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) in
            if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                // Notification permission has not been asked yet, go for it!
                print("Not yet asked for permission")
            }

            if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied {
                // Notification permission was previously denied, go to settings & privacy to re-enable
                print("Permission denied")
            }

            if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                // Notification permission was already granted
                print("Permission Granted")

            }
        })
    }
```